# lightning:recordEditForm onLoad being called twice

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning:recordEditForm that is calling "onload" function twice, there is a parameter on the event to prevent that like we have with force:recordData?

Something like: event.getParams().changeType;

My current code is:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.currentList}" var="group" indexVar="key">
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!group.Id}" objectApiName="Group__c" onsubmit="{!c.saveInfo}" onerror="{!c.handleFormError}" onload="{!c.handleFormLoad}"> 
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldList}" var="fieldAPI">
            <lightning:inputField variant="label-hidden" aura:id="quoteCategory" fieldName="{!fieldAPI}" disabled="true" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller:

```
handleFormLoad: function(component, event, helper) {
     var recUi = event.getParam("recordUi");

      console.log('recUi: ' , recUi.record.id);
},
```

Init code:

```
queryFullInformationHelper: function(component, event, helper) {
    this.showSpinner();
    var action = component.get("c.queryFullInformation");
    // set param to method
    action.setParams({
        oppId: component.get("v.OpportunityId")
    });
    // set a callBack

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var result = response.getReturnValue();

        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            if (result.Success) {

                component.set("v.opp", result.OppDTO.OppToDisplay);
                component.set("v.currentList", result.groupInfo);
                component.set("v.fieldList", result.fieldAPIList);

                this.hideSpinner();
            } else {
                if (result.ErrorMessage != undefined) {
                    this.showToast("Something Failed", result.ErrorMessage, "Error");
                    this.hideSpinner();
                }
            }
            this.hideSpinner();
        } else {
            this.hideSpinner();
        }
    });
    // enqueue the Action
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

At this point I can see twice the same record Id on console, although it is displaying the correct amount of form (in this list, 5 different Groups which means 5 different Names).

Thanks,

Comment: So, you are loading 5 forms whose Ids are in `currentList` ? Can you show full code?

Comment: Hello @salesforce-sas, thank you for all the help. I just updated with my Init code. From the server is returning a wrapper with one Opportunity, a List<Group__c> and a List<String>. I'm sure that is returning just 5 as there ins't more records created in this sandbox. Why do I need to get this onload method working properly? Because I'm showing a spinner and I want to hide it when all the forms are fully loaded.

Comment: i am actually getting it fired only once, I am not able to reproduce it. Are you modifying `currentList` anywhere else?